# Translate JQuery slideUp/slideDown into angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-directive

I implemented a slideUp/Down functionality in JQuery. Now I want to create an Angular directive to do this. My html code is

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span>
</div>
<div panel-body>
    <!-- Content to be slide up/down -->
</div>
```

js file:

```
$(document).on('click', '.panel-heading span.clickable', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.find('i').hasClass("glyphicon-chevron-up")) {
        $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
        $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    }
    else {
        $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
        $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    }
});
```

How can I make this functionality into Angular directive so that I don't need to manipulate DOM in my controller? Thanks!

Comment: Something like: https://github.com/EricWVGG/AngularSlideables